# A possible bug in Blazor .NET 8 - the page 'error' in the new Blazor Web App (WebAssembly) template redirects to 404

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

To reproduce:

Create Blazor Web App (WebAssembly) in .NET 8 and choose GLOBAL interactivity location (this is the most important thing):
[image]

you will have that project structure:

[image]

Now run application and open "/error" page, firstly you will see the error page and after 1 second you will be redirected to Not found page:

[image]

The problem exists only in **GLOBAL interactivity location**, not in per page/component interactivity location. You can even create your own new page in Components/Pages and when you try to open that page in a browser you will be also redirected to Not found page.

Comment: Yes, something is wrong. Error page should be probably in Client project. If you move it there, it works. My explanation: You start with SSR error page, then wasm part is downloaded and its `Routes.razor` kick in-> it scans through its routes and doesn't find `/error`, thus serving the not found html. Probably aspnetcore repo would be better place to share this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug.  It's behaving exactly as it's configured to.

It looks like a misconfiguration of the template.  I believe it's designed to be a static server rendered page.

Within the WASM SPA there's no route to /Error, so the page is submitted back to the server.  As it's rendered within `App`, the WASM SPA treats it as an interactive page and tries to render it interactively.  It fails because no route exists in the WASM router.

Why are you trying to route to it?

Answer (score 0):

> You can even create your own new page in Components/Pages and when you
> try to open that page in a browser you will be also redirected to Not
> found page.

If fact,you shouldn't create components in your server project.Once you applied InteractiveWebAssembly  render mode to entire app,you should move all your components from server project (except App.razor) into `.Client` project or a  library which is referered by `.Client` project

as mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#enable-support-for-interactive-render-modes):

> Blazor uses the Blazor WebAssembly hosting model to download and
> execute components that use the Interactive WebAssembly render mode. A
> separate client project is required to set up Blazor WebAssembly
> hosting for these components. The client project contains the startup
> code for the Blazor WebAssembly host and sets up the .NET runtime for
> running in a browser. The Blazor Web App template adds this client
> project for you when you select the option to enable WebAssembly
> interactivity. Any components using the Interactive WebAssembly render
> mode should be built from the client project, so they get included in
> the downloaded app bundle.

If you do want to separate the component from other components,you could try the following steps:

1, create a RCL project which is referred by your .Client project ,move Error component into it

2,add additional assembly to the Router component:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[]{typeof(RazorClassLibrary.Error).Assembly}">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

3,configured as below in Program.cs(server project):

```
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Counter).Assembly)
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Error).Assembly);
```

Comment: But Microsoft created that template, why should I change it and move these components to the client project?

Comment: Hi,@Aleksander Chelpski,what's your .net version? I tried to create a new Blazor Web App with 8.0.0-rc.2.23480.2,the error page was in .Client project